# Preg_replace - count

Tags: php, count, preg-replace

```
 $pattern = array ('/\[spoiler\]/', "/\[.spoiler\]/");

 $replace = array ("<button title=\"Click to show/hide content\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}\">Pokaż/ukryj</button><div id=\"spoiler\" style=\"display: none;\">", "</div>");

 <?php echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, '[spoiler]awdawdawd[/spoiler] ');
```

Hi, i wrote that script and i have one little problem. I need to count the number of id, that should be spoiler1, spoiler2 etc.

Comment: You could just replace `document.getElementById('spoiler')` with `this.nextSibling` and you wouldn't need IDs...

Comment: can you be more specific about "count the number of id"? also what are "spoiler1", "spoiler2", etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this with PHP you can use `preg_replace_callback` instead. See this shortened example:

```
$counter  = 1;
$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/\[spoiler\]/', 'replace_with_count', '[spoiler]awdawdawd another[spoiler]');
echo $replaced;
# will show: <button id='spoiler1'>Show 1</button>awdawdawd another<button id='spoiler2'>Show 2</button>

/**
 * Replace all occurrence with an incrementing number
 *
 * @param array $matches
 * @return string
 */
function replace_with_count($matches) {
    global $counter;
    $result = "<button id='spoiler{$counter}'>Show {$counter}</button>";
    $counter++;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: better to use `function replace_with_count($matches) use (&$counter) {` instead of global variables.